# White screen after installation

Tags: magento-1.9, apache2

I am trying to install Magento in mac 10.10, I tried both version 1 and 2, after installation.

It just show the white screen no content, chrome says "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" when I checked the apache log it says "[core:notice] [pid 87] AH00052: child pid 95385 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)"

ini_set('display_errors', 1); is added to index page but there is no any error message in the page

Developer mode has also been enabled.

---

```
Jul 21 12:48:47 dtuladharmac.local CloudKeychainProxy[730]:  __39-[UbiqitousKVSProxy doSyncWithAllPeers]_block_invoke_2 <UB--s--C---> syncWithAllPeers (null), rescheduling timer
Jul 21 12:48:55 dtuladharmac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system): Session adoption is only allowed in user domains.
Jul 21 12:48:55 dtuladharmac.local nohup[15931]: Could not adopt Background session: 125: Domain does not support specified action
Jul 21 12:48:55 dtuladharmac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system): Session adoption is only allowed in user domains.
Jul 21 12:48:55 dtuladharmac.local nohup[15932]: Could not adopt Background session: 125: Domain does not support specified action
Jul 21 12:48:55 dtuladharmac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.mysql.mysqld[15873]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Jul 21 12:48:55 dtuladharmac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.mysql.mysqld): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Jul 21 12:49:02 dtuladharmac.local secd[566]:  __SOSCCProcessSyncWithAllPeers_Server_block_invoke sync with all peers failed: (null)
```

---

this is system log issue

Answer (score 2):

Check `var/log/exception.log` and `var/log/system.log`.

Also, enable developer mode via `.htaccess`

```
#Magento Developer Mode
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"
```

Also make sure display errors is enabled in php. Check `index.php` and uncomment:

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

If still no error is returned, make sure your caching is disabled and check your webservers error logs.

Comment: Also: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=753851

Comment: I couldn't find exception.log file, and there is nothing is webserver error :(

Comment: Try a different PHP version perhaps, RE: previous link I posted. Segment fault means something in the stack has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Before you try anything else make sure you have flushed ALL available cache's
**that's all 5 options**